# Drawing cuboid with given coordinates in rgl

Tags: r, rgl

I am trying to draw a cuboid of given coordinates of vertices : (-3,-2,-5), (-3,-2,6), (-3,3,-5), (-3,3,6), (7,-2,-5), (7,-2,6), (7,3,-5), (7,3,6) using `rgl` package. That I have done in the following manner :

```
library(rgl)
vertices1 <- c( 
  -3, -2, -5, 1,
  7, -2, -5, 1,
  7,  3, -5, 1,
  -3,  3, -5, 1
)
vertices2 <- c( 
  -3, -2, 6, 1,
  7, -2, 6, 1,
  7,  3, 6, 1,
  -3,  3, 6, 1
)
vertices3 <- c( 
  -3, -2, -5, 1,
  -3, -2, 6, 1,
  -3, 3, 6, 1,
  -3,  3, -5, 1
)
vertices4 <- c(
  7, -2, -5, 1,
  7, -2, 6, 1,
  7,  3, 6, 1,
  7,  3, -5, 1
)
vertices5 <- c(
  -3, 3, -5, 1,
  7, 3, -5, 1,
  7, 3, 6, 1,
  -3, 3, 6, 1
)
vertices6 <- c(
  -3, -2, -5, 1,
  7, -2, -5, 1,
  7, -2, 6, 1,
  -3, -2, 6, 1

)
indices <- c( 1, 2, 3, 4 )
open3d()  
wire3d( qmesh3d(vertices1, indices) , col = "blue")
wire3d( qmesh3d(vertices2, indices) , col = "blue" )
wire3d( qmesh3d(vertices3, indices) , col = "blue")
wire3d( qmesh3d(vertices4, indices) , col = "blue")
shade3d(qmesh3d(vertices1, indices) , col = "blue", alpha = 0.1)
shade3d(qmesh3d(vertices2, indices) , col = "blue", alpha = 0.1)
shade3d(qmesh3d(vertices3, indices) , col = "blue", alpha = 0.1)
shade3d(qmesh3d(vertices4, indices) , col = "blue", alpha = 0.1)
shade3d(qmesh3d(vertices5, indices) , col = "blue", alpha = 0.1)
shade3d(qmesh3d(vertices6, indices) , col = "blue", alpha = 0.1)
```

[image]

Is there any better way to do it using `rgl` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More concisely, and avoiding to repeat some vertices:

```
library(rgl)

vertices <- cbind(
  c(-3,-2,-5), 
  c(-3,-2, 6), 
  c(-3, 3,-5), 
  c(-3, 3, 6), 
  c( 7,-2,-5), 
  c( 7,-2, 6), 
  c( 7, 3,-5), 
  c( 7, 3, 6)
)

indices <- cbind(
  c(1, 5, 7, 3),
  c(2, 6, 8, 4),
  c(1, 2, 4, 3),
  c(5, 6, 8, 7),
  c(3, 7, 8, 4)
  c(1, 5, 6, 2)
)

cuboid <- qmesh3d(
  vertices = vertices,
  indices = indices,
  homogeneous = FALSE
)

shade3d(cuboid, color = "blue", alpha = 0.1)
wire3d(cuboid, color = "blue")
```

Comment: It seems that if I change the ordering of `vertices` , then I also need to change the `indices`. Is there any general approach to choose `indices` according to any arbitrary set of `vertices`?  Thanks for helping!

Comment: @CatDistribution Each index correspond to a vertex, in the order they are given. You have to choose the indices which form the faces of the mesh.