# 3D Visualization: "3D"-geom_rect function in rgl?

Tags: r, rgl

Refering to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73038648/calculation-of-allowed-space-within-monte-carlo-simulated-data-of-3-variables-c) I found a solution for my first problem, but know I have a visualization question regarding rgl.

I did a tedious simulation and got a square which fits into this "space" I created with the mentioned code. In 2D I would use geom_rect to visualize it.
Is there a 3D-geom_rect function in rgl or is there a way to get multiple 3D objects in one plot?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Drawing cuboid with given coordinates in rgl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61157348/drawing-cuboid-with-given-coordinates-in-rgl)

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but not really. In my case it is necessary to plot two different things in one rgl plot. Like a ggplot object:
ggplot()+geom_point()+geom_rect()